# how to use perforce triggered build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

How to initiate a periodic basis build according to the changelist form Perforce ?

Jenkins job need to check the perforce changelist from 12.00 A.M to 8.00 P.M and need to trigger the build at 8.00 P.M every day. How to use perforce triggered build in Jenkins ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the  [Jenkins Perforce Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin) you will be able configure a Jenkins job with a Perforce Client.

In a new freestyle job you will have
[the options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Ciu.png):

1. *Advanced Project Options* in which you can specify a custom workspace. This is the folder where the P4 Plugin will sync your client. (which can then be referenced later using the WORKSPACE variable)
2. *Source Code Management* in which you can configure the Perforce client to use, and how to use it.
3. *Build Triggers* in which you can choose when you want the build. "**Poll SCM**" polls your Perforce client for any changes made according to the time parameters you specify (H/5 H(0-19) * * *  will check every 5 mins from 12:00 to 19:59), while, I believe, "**Build Periodically**" will trigger the build according to a schedule. (0 H(20) * * * will trigger a build every evening at 20:00)

I believe it's bad practice on Jenkins to force a job to run at a specific time because Jenkins uses HASH values to try and distribute load on its servers, so a better schedule would be (H H(20) * * *) as this would allow the Jenkins master to trigger the build somewhere between 20:00 and 20:59. The specific times are not random, but are generated internally from the job name

Comment: As the requester wants to trigger the build at 8pm, I don't think Poll SCM works here. The poll scm will look for changes and as soon as it finds any, its triggers a build.

The only option would be scheduled trigger. It should be set to trigger everyday at 8pm. It will automatically pick up changes that were done till now after the last build. But here too you have a problem. It will take all the changes after the previous build not the only changes that were done between 12am to 8pm.

Comment: @AmolManthalkar Poll SCM doesn't trigger immediately on change .. it has a Schedule (as described above) which will determine when the Job will check Perforce for changes, and the above mask will check for changes every night between 8pm and 9pm - after the schedule is set you can see in the job configuration form when the job will poll perforce. You are right though that the job will not trigger if there are no new changes to the repository since the last time the job run.
If the job MUST run every evening, the same mask in the "Build Periodically" field will do it.